# How to move spinner dropdown menu so selected choice can be seen?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-spinner

I'm using a spinner and have populated the dropdown menu with all of the choices.  The problem I have is that when the dropdown menu appears, it blocks what is currently selected.

Here's a picture to demonstrate and my code:

[image: Shows blocking spinner]

```
 if(field.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("select"))
            {
                CSSelect select = (CSSelect) field;

                LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
                final Spinner s = new Spinner(this);

                TextView t = new TextView(this);
                t.setText("▼");
                t.setTextSize(12);
                t.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.spinnerbg);
                t.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        s.performClick();
                    }
                });

                LinearLayout.LayoutParams slp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(400, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                s.setLayoutParams(slp);

                ll.addView(s);
                ll.addView(t);

                s.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.spinnerbg);

                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

                JSONArray choices = select.getChoices();

                for(int j = 0; j < choices.length(); j++)
                {
                    JSONObject jObj = choices.getJSONObject(j);
                    String st = jObj.getString("text");
                    list.add(st);
                }

                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                        R.layout.spinner_item, list);
                dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
                s.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

                rscroll.addView(ll, lp);
            }
```

Spinner dropdown item xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
android:singleLine="true"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:textSize="12dp"
android:textColor="#000000"/>
```

Spinner item xml:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="12sp"
android:textColor="#000000"

/>
```

How do I go from A, above, to B?  What code do I use to move the dropdown menu below?

Comment: What code do you have currently placing this menu?

Answer (score 5):

Just add the following property to Spinner in XML:

android:overlapAnchor="false"

Answer (score 2):

Have spinner mode set from dialog to dropdown:

```
 <Spinner 
        android:id="@+id/tv_power_settings_type_spinner" 
        style="@android:style/Widget.Spinner"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:popupBackground="@color/black"/>
```

To do it with code:

```
new Spinner(this, Spinner.MODE_DROPDOWN)
```

Comment: What's the java equivalent of setting spinner mode to dropdown?  I have to create the spinner dynamically.  I see setLayoutMode(...) but I don't know what parameter to pass to make it be a dropdown.

Comment: I just tried it but the problem is still there (still blocking the selected choice).  I do appreciate your help though so I did 1 up.

Comment: Did you change the constructor?

Comment: Yes I changed it to final Spinner s = new Spinner(this, Spinner.MODE_DROPDOWN);  but the dropdown menu still covers up the selected choice.